# Get postal code with autocomplete service from google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the autocompleteservice from google maps api V3 to make a custom autocomplete input.
I basically call this function to retrieve cities suggestions.

```
function getPlaces(st){
    gService.getQueryPredictions({input:st,types:['geocode']},function(predictions,status)      {
        if(status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) return false;
        for(var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++){
            console.log(prediction);
        }
        return predictions;
    });
}
```

This is working great, but i want to get the zip code associated to cities.
Like the V2 api did, [see this example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sbeau&7sFR&9sfr-FR&callback=_xdc_._rmc2d7&token=103359).

I tried to change the types option to cities, but the result is the same.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: have a look at this answer, it was really helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414445/google-maps-api-v3-cant-gecode-autocompleteservice-predictions

Answer (score 1):

In the new API the AutocompleteService only searches for guessed strings that match the text you've typed so far. To get to the actual Place object that contains address and other data, you need to use the Autocomplete object that is created when you attach the autocomplete() function to a textbox. See docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#getting_place_information

Comment: but in this case, how to use the `Autocomplete` class with a defined input string programatically? if I don't want to have a text field and already know the string I want to use as input?

Comment: @zanona You can't use Autocomplete class because that's a UI class (it attaches itself to a textbox). For your purpose you need to use the AutocompleteService class instead: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService

Comment: `autocompleteService` doesn't provide `getDetails` method as `Autocomplete`

Comment: I haven't looked at Google's geo autocomplete API in over 6 years, @Arseniy-II. Glad you posted an updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the returned prediction is a place, then it will have a `place_id` property. You need to pass that id to the `getDetails` method of the `PlacesService` class and that will return you postal information. It's a bit round about way to get the postal code, but it's the only solution I've found that works with the `AutocompleteService`

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service?hl=en_US) for the PlacesService class

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snippet:

```js
    var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {  
  var input = document.getElementById('id_address');
  var options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'in'
    }
  };

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
          document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;

        }
      }
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxcRPSsACIjdvMWRcfJBMzp4pKQXPJjj0&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="id_address" type="text" value="" />
<div id="postal_code"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't use the `AutocompleteService` class which is what the original question is asking about

Comment: Please refer to the others answers. Now you have to get the "details" to obtain an adress.